# Does the OpenJDK JVM have cache/buffers that may look like a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

I'm developing an application that runs on the OpenJDK JVM and tracking its memory usage. Its resident set size seems to be increasing over time. I'm wondering if there might be some buffering or caching going on inside the JVM that would look like this, and if there is, how do I account for that to figure out whether my application is really leaking?
[image]

This is a graph showing some statistics collected over time. The one that causes alarm is the white one (it's plotted against the right axis): that is a graph of the derivative of the processes's memory usage. It's always positive, which means memory usage is always growing.

Comment: Usually you can expect the JVM to use memory up to the value you've given with `-Xmx` argument , even if it's all garbage. Does this go (way) above that value ?

Comment: @nos: I believe you mean `-Xms`. Going over `-Xmx` would result in an OOME.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato No, I meant -Xmx. Going above -Xmx and not getting getting an OOME would signify a real leak, probably in native code.

Comment: @nos: ah, sorry, misunderstood your original comment.

Comment: Decreasing -Xms did not change anything. We moved on to bisecting our app before I saw @nos's clarification, and we found that we were, in fact, leaking somewhere. The lack of a clear-cut "yes, memory will seem to grow because x" made it clear that we needed to take another look at our application.